# should socket be set NON-BLOCKING before it is polled by select()?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

I have the memory that when we want to use select() over a socket descriptor, this socket should be set NONBLOCKING in advance.

but today, I read a source file where there seems no lines which set socket  to NON-BLOCKING
Is my memory correct or not?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

duskwuff has the right idea when he says

> In general, you do not need to set a socket as non-blocking to use it
> in select().

This is true if your kernel is POSIX compliant with regard to select(). Unfortunately, some people use Linux, which is not, as the Linux select() man page says:

> Under Linux, select() may report a socket file descriptor as "ready for
> reading", while nevertheless a subsequent read blocks. This could for
> example happen when data has arrived but upon examination has wrong
> checksum and is discarded. There may be other circumstances in which a
> file descriptor is spuriously reported as ready. Thus it may be safer
> to use O_NONBLOCK on sockets that should not block.

There was a discussion of this on lkml on or about Sat, 18 Jun 2011.  One kernel hacker tried to justify the non POSIX compliance. They honor POSIX when it's convenient and desecrate it when it's not.

He argued "there may be two readers and the second will block." But such an application flaw is non sequiter. The kernel is not expected to prevent application flaws. The kernel  has a clear duty: in all cases of the first read() after select(), the kernel must return at least 1 byte, EOF, or an error; but NEVER block. As for write(), you should always test whether the socket is reported writable by select(), before writing. This guarantees you can write at least one byte, or get an error; but NEVER block. Let select() help you, don't write blindly hoping you won't block. The Linux hacker's grumbling about corner cases, etc., are euphemisms for "we're too lazy to work on hard problems."

Suppose you read a serial port set for:

> min N; with -icanon, set N characters minimum for a completed read
>
> time N; with -icanon, set read timeout of N tenths of a second
>
> min 250 time 1

Here you want blocks of 250 characters, or a one tenth second timeout. When I tried this on Linux in non blocking mode, the read returned for every single character, hammering the CPU. It was NECESSARY to leave it in blocking mode to get the documented behavior.

So there are good reasons to use blocking mode with select() and expect your kernel to be POSIX compliant.

But if you must use Linux, Jeremy's advice may help you cope with some of its kernel flaws.

Comment: OK, I know this is old but according to https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html timeouts are ignored if non-blocking mode. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154157/termios-vmin-vtime-and-blocking-non-blocking-read-operations

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Setting a socket as non-blocking does several things:

- Makes `read()` / `recv()` return immediately with no data, instead of blocking, if there is nothing available to read on the socket.

  If you are using `select()`, this is probably a non-issue. So long as you only read from a socket when `select()` tells you it is readable, you're fine.
- Makes `write()` / `send()` return partial (or zero) writes, instead of blocking, if not enough space is available in kernel buffers.

  This one is tricky. If your application is written to handle this situation, it's great, because it means your application will not block when a client is reading slowly. However, it means that your application will need to temporarily store writable data in its own application-level buffers, rather than writing directly to sockets, and selectively place sockets with pending writes in the `writefds` set. Depending on what your application is, this may either be a lifesaver or a huge added complication. Choose carefully.
- If set before the socket is connected, makes `connect()` return immediately, before a connection is actually made.

  Similarly, this is sometimes useful if your application needs to make connections to hosts that may respond slowly while continuing to respond on other sockets, but can cause issues if you aren't careful about how you handle these half-connected sockets. It's usually best avoided (by only setting sockets as non-blocking after they are connected, if at all).

In general, you **do not** need to set a socket as non-blocking to use it in `select()`. The system call already lets you handle sockets in a basic non-blocking fashion. Some applications will need non-blocking writes, though, and that's what the flag is still needed for.

Comment: wow, these answers are a bit confusing, two answers say sockets need to be set NON-BLOCKING, 2 answers say there is no need.

Comment: @misteryes I think it depends on how strictly you define "need".  You can get away with blocking sockets if you are careful to only call recv() exactly once on the socket after select() indicated it is read-for-read, on the assumption that recv() will not block in that situation.  But what if recv() blocks anyway (e.g. due to that Linux "feature" described in Trifle Menot's answer), or what if somewhere in your codebase you later forget the only-call-recv()-once rule and end up calling it twice? Then your program may be blocked in recv(), possibly for a very long time, and otherwise frozen. :(

Answer (score 0):

send() and write() block if you provide more data than can be fitted into the socket send buffer. Normally in select() programming you don't want to block anywhere except in select(), so you use non-blocking mode.

With certain Windows APIs it indeed essential to use non-blocking mode.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you are using select(), you are using it is the basis of an event loop; and when using an event loop you want the event loop to block only inside select() and never anywhere else.  (The reason for that is so that your program will always wake up whenever there is something to do on any of the sockets it is handling -- if, for example, your program was blocked inside recv() for socket A, it would be unable to handle any data coming in on socket B until it got some data from socket A first to wake it up; and vice versa).

Therefore it is best to set all sockets non-blocking when using select().  That way there is no chance of your program getting blocked on a single socket and ignoring the other ones for an extended period of time.