# COM-port read problem on ARM64 architecture (Radxa Rock)

Tags: serial-port, debian, arm64

I am programming on ARM64 architecture (Radxa Rock) serial port read-write via USB in Debian 11 using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10. Compiling and running on a remote Linux machine. The project is a VS Community 2022 C++ console application for Linux. The write to the port theoretically works. The unsolvable issue is that regardless of any methods or approaches used, it completely freezes upon attempting the read(...) command. The baud rates are synchronized, other basic parameters are also set properly.
Terminal programs for Linux handle my tasks perfectly - they write and read. Examining the code of these programs shows identical port polling. I've been unable to resolve the issue in any way, whether by programming from Windows to the remote machine or by directly compiling in VS Code on the Linux machine. No advice found, including AI suggestions, has helped, or they are already implemented. The program simply hangs on the read command. No error, no exception. It just stops.

I have read the documentation, used various examples, tried working with different libraries both directly and indirectly, searched through forums, the internet, and consulted AI. I've utilized everything I knew.
On line  61 ( ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, read_data, sizeof(read_data) - 1);) the debugger stops and hangs somewhere. Only the "stop debugging" button is available

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>


int main()
{
    printf("Hello? I'm %s!\n", "ConsoleLinuxCPP");

    const char* port_name = "/dev/ttyUSB0"; // Имя вашего COM-порта в Linux
    int fd = open(port_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    if (fd == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "COM port opening error..." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Setting com-port parameters
    // Set the baud rate, data bits, stop bits, parity, etc.
    // This may require additional system calls to set parameters.
    struct termios tty;
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0) {
        perror("Error getting serial port attributes");
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }

    // Setting the baud rate (baud rate)
    cfsetospeed(&tty, B9600);  // For example, 9600 bit/s

    // Other settings
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;    // Disable parity bit
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;    // One stop beat
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;     // Clear character size bits
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;        // 8 data bits
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;   // Disable hardware flow control

    // Применить настройки
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        perror("Error setting serial port attributes");
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }

    // The port is now ready to be used with speed settings and read options

    //const char data[] = "Hello, world!";
    const char data[] = "$01L1\n";
    ssize_t bytes_written = write(fd, data, sizeof(data) - 1);

    if (bytes_written == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Sending data error" << std::endl;
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }

    char read_data[100];
    ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, read_data, sizeof(read_data) - 1);

    if (bytes_read == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Receive data error" << std::endl;
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }

    read_data[bytes_read] = '\0';
    std::cout << "Read from COM port: " << read_data << std::endl;

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you successfully read if your buffer size is less than the amount of incoming data (e.g. `char read_data[4];`)?

Comment: (I removed the Microsoft tags because Visual Studio on Windows is just your editor.  Everything interesting including compile/link/run is all happening in Linux)

Comment: Probably helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20154157/103167

Comment: Ben Voigt. No. The result is similar. Freeze ( if  read buffer size is less than the amount of incoming data? etc/ 4